# Export 3d models with lights and camera info

Tags: export, blend4web

I want to export the scene from blender which includes the model,lights and camera info. So I can code my 3js to read those info to setup the scene in the web.
GLTF only saves the mesh info.
How could I possibly achieve it

Many thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures